# Is there a reason why my Nativescript app won't upload to S3 using 'nativescript-aws-sdk'?

Tags: amazon-s3, nativescript

I am trying to follow the demo from https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-aws-sdk to upload an image but when I run my app, it returns this error

`ERROR Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
        Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
        JS:     com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<clinit>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:65)
        JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
        JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1209)
        JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1096)
        JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1083)
        JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1063)
        JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1055)
        JS:     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7327)
        JS:     android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160)
        JS:     android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
        JS:     android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        JS:     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773)
         JS:     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
         JS:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Hand...`

for reference here is what our component.ts file looks like:

```
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Use the "ngOnInit" handler to initialize data for the view.
        S3.init(<any>{
            endPoint: '',
            accessKey: 'our accessKey',
            secretKey: 'our secretKey',
            type: 'static' }); // <= Try calling this before the app starts
    }

export function uploadFile() {
  const s3 = new S3();
  const imageUploaderId = s3.createUpload({
    file: '~src/app/assets/Lena.jpg',
    bucketName: 'our bucketName',
    key: `ns__Lena.jpg`,
    acl: 'public-read',
    completed: (error, success) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`Download Failed :-> ${error.message}`);
      }
      if (success) {
        console.log(`Download Complete :-> ${success.path}`);
      }
    },
    progress: progress => {
      console.log(`Progress : ${progress.value}`);
    }
  });

  s3.pause(imageUploaderId);
  s3.resume(imageUploaderId);
  s3.cancel(imageUploaderId);

}
```

Any help would be appreciate plz. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been an issue [for some time](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-aws-sdk/issues/8).

From a totally naïve perspective, I would suggest installing log4j in your app, since that's the package that is failing to be found. The proper solution is obviously have to have the plugin do that for you, but doing it yourself should fix the problem.